# How to set up HTML tracking code in Google tag manager with transaction ID data

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have to implement tracking pixel code on my thank you page through google tag manager. There a transaction ID variable in the pixel code to track the transaction. Below is the tracking pixel code.

```
<iframe src="https://t1.example.com/p.ashx?a=284&e=302&t=TRANSACTION_ID" height="1" width="1" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

How do I set up the tracking tag which can pass the transaction ID from thank you page to the tracking code in GTM?

Comment: Do you have dataLayer implemented on your site? Does it contain the transaction ID? Or you need to read the ID from the DOM?

Comment: I want read the transaction ID from the url on thank you page which will be unique for every customer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your clarification in your comment, and assuming your visitors arrive on a similar URL: `https://www.example.com/thankyou.html?transactionId=1234`

You should set up a variable, which reads the ID from the URL. It needs to be URL type variable, with similar settings:

[image]

You can now use this variable in your tags and scripts, referring to it as `{{Transaction ID}}`, or by any GTM variable you choose and provide as a variable name in GTM.

In your specific case, based on my variable name on the image, you can create a Custom HTML type tag:

```
<iframe src="https://t1.example.com/p.ashx?a=284&e=302&t={{Transaction ID}}" height="1" width="1" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

**Edit:**

An other option would be to push this data into the dataLayer, and set up a Data Layer Variable to read it from there. E.g.

```
<script>
  var transactionId = //your code to get the variable

  dataLayer.push({
    event: 'transaction',
    transactionId: transactionId
  });
</script>
```

In this case, your variable setup looked like this:

[image]

Please note, that you need to set up the relevant trigger to listen to `transaction` event. The benefit of this solution is that multiple tags can now rely on this GTM variable.

Nevertheless, a third option could be to use only one custom HTML, with something like this, where you create the iframe with JavaScript, and add the transaction ID to the URL in the `src` attribute:

```
<script>
var transactionId = //your code to get the variable

var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.style.height = "1px";
iframe.style.width = "1px";
iframe.style.border = "none";
iframe.src = "https://t1.example.com/p.ashx?a=284&e=302&t=" + transactionId;
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
</script>
```

Comment: The transaction ID in the URL is encoded and I decode it on the thank you page. Should I set up it as the data layer variable? Which tag type should I use for the tracking code like custom HTML?

Comment: I've added info on the tag type (Custom HTML), and I've added further possible solutions, that might better fit your needs. Hope that helps. Please let me know, if I can help to clarify any parts of the answer.

Comment: I have added the script on the page directly.